# How to display only the content between opening and closing tags in XML file?

Tags: xml, numeric-data

How to search the XML file using grep or similar for a particular tag but show only the content between opening and closing tags? Here is the exact tag I'd like to locate:

`<max-diskusage>1024000000</max-diskusage>`

But I would like to get just the 1024000000 part and not the tag.

That is a storage size in bytes and convert that to 1 gb IF POSSIBLE or any results converted to GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `xmlstarlet` to parse the XML document for any instance of the `max-diskusage` tag, extracting its value, and then using GNU `numfmt` to convert the number of bytes to SI units:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//max-diskusage' -nl file | numfmt --to=si
```

With the short example in the question in `file`, this returns the string `1.1G`.  Using `--to=iec` (to get the traditional power-of-two sizes) in place of `--to=si`, it returns `977M`. Use `--to=si --round=down` to get `1.0G`.

Comment: Works like magic!